# How to place first two pages as two column, and thereafter one column

Tags: two-column, multicol

I am using following document class,

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint]{revtex4}
```

This is for one column page writing,
In this document class, I wish to write 2nd and third page (first is for abstract) as two-column style, and rest as one column page style.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried issuing the commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` in the appropriate places?

Comment: yes! I tried,but it didn't work out.

Comment: You can use the multicol package `\usepackage{multicol}`:

        \begin{multicols}{2}
            %your text
        \end{multicols}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following helped in getting the required template.

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{widetext} \noindent
\lipsum[3]
\end{widetext}
\end{document}
```

[image]